# Vue.js automatically restore after data changes

Tags: vue.js

1、 bind a src element in img tag (Web App)

```
<img :src="postForm.avatar" id="avatar" v-show="postForm.avatar" style="position:absolute ; width:100%;height:100%; left:0;right:0" @click="preview('avatar')" />
```

postForm is a object

2、Get the avatar from the server and set it like  `http://www.test.com/1.jpg`

3、The avatar can be set by user form the mobile , when user set the image from mobile , avatar will change to `/storage/emulated/0/wqysphoto/1554795411613.jpg` (moble local url)

this is set code

> this.$set(this.postForm,"avatar",fileURL)

The the strange things is happen  after set the local url ,the avatar will restore to `http://www.test.com/1.jpg`  automatically why?

PS this question only occurring in android

```js
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#data-box',
        data: {
            postForm: {
                avatar: "",
                idcard_number: "",
                idcard: "",
                certifications: "",
                teacher_certificate: ""
            },
            source: ""
        },
        created: function() {},
        watch: {
            'postForm.avatar': function(val) {
                if (!HELP_TOOL.isEmpty(val)) {
                    console.log("set img avatar: " + val)
                    $api.attr($api.dom("#avatar"), 'src', val);
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
  
            uploadPhoto: function(psource) {
                var self = this;
                api.actionSheet({
                    cancelTitle: 'cancel',
                    buttons: ['cmaera', 'album'],
                    style: {

                    }
                }, function(ret, err) {
                    var index = ret.buttonIndex;
                    if (index == 1) {
                        HELP_TOOL.reqPermission('camera', function() {
                            getPicture('camera', function(url) {
                                self.uploadFile(url, psource)
                            })
                        })
                    } else if (index == 2) {
                        HELP_TOOL.reqPermission('photos', function() {
                            getPicture('album', function(url) {
                                self.uploadFile(url, psource)
                            })
                        })
                    }
                });
            },
            uploadFile: function(fileURL, psource) {

                var self = this
                
                HTTP.http_post({
                    url: HTTP_URL.uploadFile,
                    timeout: 50,
                    data: {
                        values: {
                            key: "photo"
                        },
                        files: {
                            api_file: fileURL
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(ret) {
                        this.$set(this.postForm,psource,fileURL)
                    }
                })
            },
            preview: function(psource) {
                //open preview url
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="data-box">
<div class="add-image-box aui-flex-col aui-flex-bottom">
                    <div class="add-image" style="width:3.0rem; height:3rem;background:#f5f5f5;position:relative">
                        <img :src="postForm.avatar" id="avatar" v-show="postForm.avatar" style="position:absolute ; width:100%;height:100%; left:0;right:0" @click="preview('avatar')" />
                        <img src="../../image/button/plus_btn.png"  v-show="!postForm.avatar" style="position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.5);" @click="uploadPhoto('avatar')">
                    </div>
                    <div class="upload-btn aui-flex-auto aui-text-right aui-font-size-14 aui-text-info" @click="uploadPhoto('avatar')">
                        upload{{postForm.avatar}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you create a codesandbox or codepen for this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't change the data value. As `src` is bound to `postForm.avatar`, you shoud be changing this data instead of modifying DOM directly:

```
this.postForm.avatar = $api.dom("#avatar")
```

instead of

```
$api.attr($api.dom("#avatar"), 'src', val);
```